# unable to call webservice from osgi bundle

Tags: osgi, cxf, jbpm, apache-karaf

while deploying an `osgi` bundle on `karaf` ,which is internally calling webservice through `jbpm` process..showing below error...

```
ERROR | Error in thread 'ActiveMQ Session Task-1'
javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder$ConfigurationError: Provider
org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl not found
         at javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder$2.run(FactoryFinder.java:143)
         at javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder.doPrivileged(FactoryFinder.java:251)
         at javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:137)
         at javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder.access$300(FactoryFinder.java:44)
         at javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder$3.run(FactoryFinder.java:242)
         at javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder.doPrivileged(FactoryFinder.java:251)
         at javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:173)
         at javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider.provider(Provider.java:43)
         at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:35)
         at net.webservicex.GeoIPService.<init>(GeoIPService.java:42)
         at org.bt.nga.workitemhandlers.GeoIPServiceWorkItemHandler.executeWorkItem(GeoIPServiceWorkItemHandler.java:33)
         at org.drools.core.process.instance.impl.DefaultWorkItemManager.internalExecuteWorkItem(DefaultWorkItemManager.java:71)
         at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.WorkItemNodeInstance.internalTrigger(WorkItemNodeInstance.java:138)
         at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.trigger(NodeInstanceImpl.java:173)
         at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.triggerNodeInstance(NodeInstanceImpl.java:366)
         at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.triggerCompleted(NodeInstanceImpl.java:325)
         at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.StartNodeInstance.triggerCompleted(StartNodeInstance.java:73)
         at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.StartNodeInstance.internalTrigger(StartNodeInstance.java:44)
         at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.NodeInstanceImpl.trigger(NodeInstanceImpl.java:173)
         at org.jbpm.ruleflow.instance.RuleFlowProcessInstance.internalStart(RuleFlowProcessInstance.java:35)
         at org.jbpm.process.instance.impl.ProcessInstanceImpl.start(ProcessInstanceImpl.java:236)
         at org.jbpm.workflow.instance.impl.WorkflowProcessInstanceImpl.start(WorkflowProcessInstanceImpl.java:439)
         at org.jbpm.process.instance.ProcessRuntimeImpl.startProcessInstance(ProcessRuntimeImpl.java:208)
         at org.jbpm.process.instance.ProcessRuntimeImpl.startProcess(ProcessRuntimeImpl.java:191)
         at org.jbpm.process.instance.ProcessRuntimeImpl.startProcess(ProcessRuntimeImpl.java:183)
         at org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.startProcess(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1787)
         at org.bt.nga.service.api.ProcessEngineImpl.executeProcess(ProcessEngineImpl.java:48)
         at org.bt.nga.consumer.ActiveMQListener.onMessage(ActiveMQListener.java:52)
         at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageConsumer.dispatch(ActiveMQMessageConsumer.java:1401)
         at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSessionExecutor.dispatch(ActiveMQSessionExecutor.java:131)
         at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSessionExecutor.iterate(ActiveMQSessionExecutor.java:202)
         at org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner.runTask(PooledTaskRunner.java:133)
         at org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner$1.run(PooledTaskRunner.java:48)
         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: How do you call the webservice? Is this code provided by jbpm or written by you?

Comment: this doesn't look like a stacktrace from Karaf: bundles versions are not shown. Could you add some context, like which version do you use?

Comment: I am calling webservice using jbpm process which is written inside karaf bundle...and above is the stack trace what i have got from karaf. i am using latest relase apache-karaf-4.0.4.

Answer (score 0):

This error says that some bundle tried to load the class `org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl` but failed to do so, perhaps because of a missing import.

I can't say any more than that because there is not enough information in the question.

Comment: yes that i know but the same bundle is running fine in eclipse without any extra import or jars.
I think eclipse already have some dependency jar to deal with webservice but karaf does not by default ..
but not getting extacly what jars is required to fix this.

Comment: So if you have the JARs you can search for this class.